# Filter a file line by line using flume interceptors

Tags: regex, hadoop, hadoop2, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to configure a flume agent that reads from a .csv or .xl3.  An example of file:

```
ClientA  ClientB  Start-time  End-time    Duration    Status 
35862515 36958452 16/01/2017  16/01/2017  10          good
32456988 22583694 16/01/2017  16/01/2017  05          good
35968478 36985724 16/01/2017  16/01/2017
32456988 22583694 16/01/2017  16/01/2017  01          good
```

I want the agent filter the file line by line. If the Duration is Not null, the event will be send to hdfs /usr/admin/Good_Call, Otherwise, the event will be send to another path /usr/admin/Bad_Call.

How to do that using the flume config, the interceptors

Answer (score 0):

You can use [taildir sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#taildir-source) and [regex extractor interceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-extractor-interceptor). As result of regex extractor, you will have different headers for "good" and "bad" lines. Finally, add [multiplexing channel selector](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#multiplexing-channel-selector) which will decide depending on a value of header where to send event.